# How to update UI in a Flutter app with new daily content?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, auto-update

It is a simple app with a few pages. I just need to update one page daily with new content(text to be precise).

In a way that the user does not need to update the app on the Play Store, but simply when he opens the app to see the new content that i want to put on the app.

What should i use? is it Firebase or something else? and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are new firebase can be a way to go. Since firebase is a realtime database there are several ways to actually update the texts in your application.
The best would be to make an admin application where you can connect the textfields firestore queries of updating. This will help update the data to firestore and since it's real time database it will instantly get updated to user application.
If it is a small application like you said and if you really don't want to go and hassle with another application just to update the data, you can just update it in firestore tab in firebase and everything will be good to go. This is as simple as it can get. Don't forget to use streambuilders in your app to get realtime updates from firestore.

Comment: this is pretty helpful, but the thing is i am just starting with flutter and still do not understand some stuff. if you can explain how to use streambuilders and where, and where to click so that i can write a new data that will be updated, would be even more helpful. you can message me or comment here, i would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your data are coming from.
If they come from an API, then just do a GET API call once a day or when the user refreshes.
If it's custom content, then Firebase is a good option. You could do the same as above or listen to Firestore for changes via Stream.

Comment: it is a custom content. how to use Stream and how to listen to changes from Firestore, that is what i am not understanding. If you can comment here or message me with more details about this, i would appreciate it a lot.